# RESTEasy: what is a path parameter?

Tags: resteasy

Is a path parameter ***@PathParam("make")***  or **make** that is after the @PathParam or is it ***make, model, and year*** meaning any variable that is in the path surrounded by braces:

```
@Path("/cars/{make}")
@Produces("image/jpeg")
public class CarResource 
{
   @GET
   @Path("/{model}/{year}")   
   public returnType Fx (@PathParam("make") String make { ... }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

All of `{make}`, `{model}` and `{year}` *can* be injected via @PathParam as they are all "arguments supplied via the [URL] *path*". As pointed out they are all annotated for extraction via @Path and curly braces.

However, the value is only bound to a *parameter* when (and where) it is consumed. In the given code, *only `make` is a parameter* which is bound to the `/cars/{make}` *path*; neither `{model}` or `{year}` are parameters in context.

---

While I argue the case that it the final binding that makes it a parameter, there is also an argument for it being a parameter when it is merely part of the path template - that is, the path parsing itself "uses" the *value* of the URI and supplies a parameter "binding", even if not directly exposed. Consider [this wording](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/PathParam.html):

> @QueryParam: value - Defines the name of the *URI template parameter* whose value will be used to initialize the value of *the annotated method parameter*, class field or property.

Comment: I don't understand your response, and I don't think it answers the original question "what is a path parameter?" etc.